# Get records from one table array which are not present in another table records in postgres

Tags: arrays, postgresql-9.6

I want to get records from array of one table which are not present in another  table column. Following are the tables;

automobile_data

```
   -----------------------------------------------
    veh_id |             vehicle_types              
    --------+---------------------------------------
        1  | {"byd_tang","laferrari"} 
        2  | {"sonata","jaguarxf"}        
        3  | {"swift","teslax","mirai"}              
        4  | {"volt","viper"}                        
        5  | {"ferrariff","bmwi8"}   
    ------------------------------------------------
```

vehicle

```
   -----------------------------------------------
     vehicle_name |  id              
   ------------------------------------------------
      byd_tang    |   1
      laferrari   |   1     
      sonata      |   2         
      jaguarxf    |   2                  
       swift      |   3
      teslax      |   3  
   ------------------------------------------------
```

Require following output;

```
    -----------------------------------------------
     vehicle_name | veh_id              
    ------------------------------------------------
      mirai       |   3
      volt        |   4    
      viper       |   4         
      ferrariff   |   5                
      bmwi8       |   5
    ------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using first unnest the array from table automobile_data and then find name which is not exists in vehicle table;

```
SELECT  c.vehicle_name, c.veh_id
  FROM
   (
    SELECT veh_id, unnest("vehicle_types") as vehicle_name
    FROM automobile_data
    ) c  where not exists 
( SELECT FROM vehicle
      where vehicle_name = c.vehicle_name);
```